# How to pass file name to ADD EXTRACT in imacros

Tags: csv, imacros

Suppose this is my file name startLine.iim

```
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\user\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\status.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1
SET abc {{!COL1}}
```

And this is my another file endLine.iim

```
FILEDELETE NAME=status.csv
ADD !EXTRACT startLine.iim

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\user\Documents\iMacros\Downloads FILE=status.csv
```

What I'm doing is I'm extracting data from a .csv file from startLine.iim file and processing it and deleting the file status.csv and again taking the  updated value by using `ADD !EXTRACT startLine.iim` and saving it back to status.csv.
I wanted to know how to pass a file name to ADD !EXTRACT?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable:

```
SET !VAR0 profileData.csv
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR0}}
```

Or quotemarks to specify a filename as a string:

```
ADD !EXTRACT "profileData.csv"
```

Comment: Yes Thanks...It worked very well. Thanks for your effort and time